# JAVA GUI Label Output Error

Tags: java, user-interface

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class Stock {

    private JFrame frame;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Stock window = new Stock();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Stock() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblBrickStock = new JLabel("10");
        lblBrickStock.setBounds(48, 62, 46, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblBrickStock);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Bricks");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int bricks = Integer.parseInt(lblBrickStock.getText());
                bricks--;
                if (bricks <= 10) {
                    lblBrickStock.setText(String.valueOf(bricks));
                }
            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(38, 28, 89, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);


    }

}
```

I have created this stock program which is a prototype for a future program I am creating. What this program does is when you press the button the number in the label decreases. What I cannot do is that in the label I want it to say something like "10 remaining" and only for the number to decrease. It works with just the number but when I add the text I receive a whole host of errors. Any ways to work around or would I have to just use a separate label?

Comment: If you have a counter, you can keep an instance variable `int counter` instead of getting the current value from the label

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a instance member `counter` to keep track of the number instead of getting the current values from the label text

```
public class Stock{
    private int counter = 10;
    ...
}
```

And your action listener could be like :

```
btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        counter--;
        if (counter <= 10) {
            lblBrickStock.setText(counter + " remaining");
        }
    }
});
```

That way, you don't have to parse the `lblBrickStock.getText` into a numeric value, and don't risk to get a parse exception if this is not a numeric value anymore.

Here is a small snipper showing how to use a variable in an anonymous inner class (the action listener)

```
public class TestFrame extends JFrame{
    private int counter = 10;

    public TestFrame(){
        this.setTitle("Labo - TestFrame");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        this.getContentPane().add(new JButton(new AbstractAction() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println(counter--);
            }
        }));

        this.setVisible(true);
        this.pack();
    }
}
```

I clicked 3 times :

> 10
>   9
>   8

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply I haven't working on this over the weekend. When I insert the counter variable this gives an error. Is there a way of resolving this. I think it is because of the actionlistener method maybe?

Comment: @PeterToole what is the error ? The instance MUST be an instance member, it can't be a local variable define in the method where you ave the line `btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {...`

Comment: I'm using an IDE and it says counter cannot be resolved of a variable

Comment: Did you declared `int counter` in the class where like I did, @PeterToole? Because it seems you didn't.

Comment: Yes I put in in and it just doesn't recognise it, I asked a friend and they said it is because the ActionListener is like in it's own private method something like that

Comment: @PeterToole Your friend would be right if the variable `counter` would be declare in the method, but since this is (supposed to be) a instance member (declare in the class), this is valid. A `local` instance must be final (or effectively final), not a instance member.

Comment: I do not know what this means shall I create a new question and put my code in?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170996/discussion-between-peter-toole-and-axelh).

Comment: See the edit @PeterToole, this is how this should be used. If not, simply use the `edit` button below your question

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
int bricks = Integer.parseInt(lblBrickStock.getText());
```

you try to parse to Integer value with String inside. To avoid exception you can use:                 `int bricks = Integer.parseInt(lblBrickStock.getText().replaceAll("\\D+",""));`

but better idea would be static counter (as @AxelH mentioned in comment) instead of getting value from JLabel.

Comment: And in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50252918/4391450) too ;) your solution is nice but this isn't really readable.

Comment: @AxelH if I were op I would use your answer. +1

Comment: Also, if you have label like  `123 lines remaining from "file1"`. You will have a value of `1231` ;)

Comment: Of course, you are right but OP has to have some knowledge about code. I hope he tried to check what this code do.

Comment: Like you said, OP need to learn, you should break your line in multiple statement and explain what `\\D` means ;)